# Divide mesh according to level of detail

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry, mesh, cgal

#### Background

I need to remesh by OpenVDB, like what [Blender remesh](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) does:

[image: Blender screenshot]

> Voxel
>
> Uses an OpenVDB to generate a new manifold mesh from the current geometry while trying to preserve the mesh’s original volume.

#### Problem

The problem is that OpenVDB gets a constant *voxel size*. But I have meshes with varying polygon density/granularity, i.e. high-detail and low-detail components. To preserve the topology of high-detail components, the *voxel size* has to be too small for the whole 3d model.

[image: Polygon granularity/density]

#### Possible workaround

A mesh might be broken down into distinct components of higher detail and lower detail.

#### Question

Is there any algorithm or library to help me break down the mesh into distinct components according to level of detail? I looked at [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html), but I couldn't figure out.

Comment: In what I see above I have the impression that the high res and the low res mesh are not connected. Can't you mesh them separately?

Comment: @AndreasFabri Right. If I intend to mesh them separately, first I have to identity them. But I have problem identifying low-detail and high-detail components =)

Answer (score 1):

In CGAL if you want to have an element of size depending on the curvature of the input, you should go for a remeshing algorithm like [this one](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2remesh_polyhedral_surface_8cpp-example.html). The draw back is that if you want the mesh algorithm to preserve some feature edges they must be detected and passed to the mesher.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look =)